# Symbolic integration of Modified Bessel Functions using sympy and Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like to use `sympy` to solve a definite integral that I know that Mathematica can solve. In Mathematica the following line

```
Integrate[z^2 (BesselI[0, z^2] - BesselI[1, z^2]) Exp[-z^2], {z, 0, x}]
```

yields

```
1/3 x^3 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2,3/2},{1,5/2},-2 x^2]-1/10 x^5 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2,5/2},{3,7/2},-2 x^2]
```

It would prefer to use `python` with `sympy` for this and I try to with the following code

```
import sympy;
x, z = sympy.var('x z');
sympy.integrate( z**2*(sympy.besseli(0,z**2)-sympy.besseli(1,z**2))*sympy.exp(-z**2) ,(z,0,x));
```

Unfortunately, the computation just hangs. I give up after about 30-40 minutes of waiting. In Mathematica, it takes less than a second. If I change the integrand, then I can get `sympy` to solve it. Such as

```
sympy.integrate( z**2*sympy.besseli(0,z**2) ,(z,0,x));
```

yields

```
x**3*gamma(3/4)*hyper((3/4,), (1, 7/4), -x**4/4)/(4*gamma(7/4))
```

I am a long time Mathematica user and have a pretty good sense of how to get it to solve tricky integrals. As a new `sympy` users I lack that experience.

- Are there any flags I could add?
- Are there other ways to solve this problem in `sympy`?
- If this integral is not possible with `sympy`, is there a way to understand sympy's limitations? Such as how `sympy` does integration versus Mathematica.

Comment: Update: My current solution is to solve the integral in Mathematica and then  type it into my sympy script.